# How to get image color mode (Greyscale,CMYK or RGB) of an JPEG Image?

Tags: c#

i want to find whether the particular image is CMYK/GrayScale/RGB. how to find the color mode of the image in C#.NET/VB.NET/ASP.NET. Pls, help me

Comment: The representation of the colors in the image is converted from RGB to Y′CBCR, consisting of one luma component (Y'), representing brightness, and two chroma components, (CB and CR), representing color. This step is sometimes skipped. (Wiki on Jpeg)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using  System.Drawing.Image object.

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileStream);
```

using `img` object you can retrieve `img.PixelFormat;`. 
I hope this will works for you.

Comment: HI sir,I have always getting PixelFormat = Format24bppRgb

Comment: But i need another format for grayscale ,CMYK....Can you please tell me how to access ImageFlag For check  grayscale ,CMYK ,etc in Image?